# Existence of an inverse of a multivariate function

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Consider a function $h: \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$. I define that "$h$ has an inverse in the second component" if there exists a function $h^{-1}: \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ such that  for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ holds $$y= h^{-1}(h(x,y),x).$$ In other words, if $h(x,y)=z$ then $h^{-1}$ is a function such that $y=h^{-1}(z,x)$. Denote a family $I=\{h:  h \text{ has an inverse in the second component}\}$.

Can you tell me something about this family $I$? E.g. if $h$ is smooth, does it imply that $h\in I$? Probably not, but I would like to have some sufficient condition that is easily checked.

Comment: Inverse function theorem. If $h$ is differentiable and the partial derivative with respect to $y$ of $h(x,y)$ is invertible then $h$ is in $I$. This holds even for locally Lipschitz functions (See the book of Clarke on nonsmooth optimization).

Comment: A [continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function#Inverses_and_derivatives) function of a single variable is invertible if and only if it is strictly increasing or strictly decreasing. The same holds for $y\mapsto h(x,y)$ when that's continuous for every fixed $x$. I believe you want to write $y=h^{-1}(x,h(x,y))$. The argument $x$ is just a "bystander". You can apply everything we know about inverse functions to the one- variable function $y\mapsto h(x,y)$.